# Vue 3 / Nuxt 3 Scoped slot with generic data type inferred from props

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I want to implement a carousel component in Nuxt v3. The component receives an array of items. The component only implements the logic, not the styling or structuring.

Here is my component now:

`components/tdx/carousel.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="last"></slot>
    <div v-for="item in items">
      <slot
        name="item"
        v-bind="item"
      ></slot>
    </div>
    <slot name="next"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
  items: {
    type: [],
    required: true,
  },
  spotlight: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1,
    validator(value: number) {
      return value > 0;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

The logic of the carousel here is not important.

In the parent component I then can use the component like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <TdxCarousel :items="exampleArray">
      <template #item="{ title, description }">
        <p class="font-semibold text-2xl">{{ title }}</p>
        <hr />
        <p>{{ description }}</p>
      </template>
    </TdxCarousel>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const exampleArray = ref([
  {
    title: 'Item 1',
    description: 'Desc of item 1',
  },
  {
    title: 'Item 2',
    description: 'Desc of item 2',
  },
]);
</script>
```

This works fine. What I want in addition to this is typings. The types of `title` and `description` are of course any since in the props of `carousel.vue` the type of the items is `unknown[]`.

I found this [article](https://logaretm.com/blog/generically-typed-vue-components/) that show how to make a generic component but I don't want this since I would have to mess with the auto import system from nuxt.

How can I achieve type inference from the given items in the `carousel.vue` props?

Comment: I have no idea on how to help you with this question but wanted to say that your question is well written (not common here). Good luck!

Comment: Well thanks I guess xD

Comment: @kissu he wants something like in this [tip](https://youtu.be/hBk4nV7q6-w?t=302), this is not achievable easily in template/script setup syntax, but he can do that with TSX syntax

Comment: Your use case is exactly the same as mentioned [here](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/pull/1964#issuecomment-1273780706)

Comment: This would have solved my problem perfectly but I didn't bring this to work with nuxt. I suspect this is because of the autoimport feature of nuxt, since there I cannot declare the type :(

Comment: You can define the type of the `props.items` to `any[]` and cast the type of your variables when using like that: `#item="{ title, description }: { title: string, description: string}"` This approach is not the solution but at least it helps on typing

Comment: @Duannx for now this is a good workaround, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update: May 2023

As of Vue 3.3, generic components are [officially supported](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3#generic-components).

You need to define a generic parameter. Modify your `carousel.vue` component to use the `generic` attribute in the `<script setup>` tag, as well as convert it to use type-based method for `defineProps` in order for it to pick up on the generic properly.

```html
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T extends any">
withDefaults(
  defineProps<{ items: T[]; spotlight?: number }>(), {
  spotlight: 1,
});
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="last"></slot>
    <div v-for="item in items">
      <slot
        name="item"
        v-bind="item">
      </slot>
    </div>
    <slot name="next"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

Now, the props on the slot will be properly inferred from the type of items.

[image: Here I pass an array of objects with ids, each of type string]

[image: It properly infers the type of {id}]

### Before May 2023

- [RFC #436](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/436)

In earlier versions of VSCode/Volar, you needed to enable [an experimental flag](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/pull/1964).
It required enabling the `experimentalRfc436` option your tsconfig.json under `vueCompilerOptions`.

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  // ...
  "vueCompilerOptions": {
    "experimentalRfc436": true
  }
}
```

This is no longer necessary as it is enabled by default in recent versions of Volar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already tried that. I suppose this works with vue3. With nuxt3 this does not work because of the auto imports. This is a great answer but I am not going to accept it. I think this is a problem for a lot of people. We will probably see a more worked out solution to this problem in the next few months (atleast I believe it) where I hope that nuxt also supports this :)

Comment: In the latest vue release this is now officially supported. https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3#generic-components Do you wan't to update your answer? Will accept it once updated. If not I can provide an updated answer

Comment: @GionRubitschung I've updated the answer to explain official support.